# How to properly change coordinate system using Direction Cosine Matrix?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

I am trying to model the behavior of a rocket using Simulink. I use Newton and Euler's laws to compute the accelerations based on the forces and torques on the rocket. I am using two coordinate systems:

- The flat-Earth coordonate system, that I will denote $E$;
- The rocket frame, $B$.

Let us say that two forces are acting on the rocket:

- The thruster's force, expressed in $B$;
- The gravity, expressed in $E$.

**My goal is to compute the rocket position in $E$.**

Using Newton's law, I can compute the acceleration of the rocket in its own frame, $B$. The gravity force can be passed to the $B$ frame using the Direction Cosine Matrix (DCM), assuming I know the Euler angles.
I can integrate the acceleration  $\textbf{a}_B$ to find the speed $\textbf{v}_B$. Then, I can use the DCM to compute $\textbf{v}_E$, and finally integrate one last time to find $\textbf{x}_E$.

Great, it works, I compared it with Simulink's 6DOF block, and I have the same results.

Now, out of curiosity, I tried to change one thing, thinking the result would be the same: I use the DCM before the first integration. Therefore, instead of having:
$$\textbf{a}_B \xrightarrow{\int} \textbf{v}_B \xrightarrow{DCM} \textbf{v}_E \xrightarrow{\int}\textbf{x}_E$$
I have:
$$\textbf{a}_B \xrightarrow{DCM} \textbf{a}_E \xrightarrow{\int} \textbf{v}_E \xrightarrow{\int}\textbf{x}_E$$

And now, the values of $\textbf{x}_E$ are completely different. I'm guessing this is due to the derivative of $\textbf{v}$ in Newton's law that must be expressed in $E$, but I am unsure why this changes the results.

In another project, I had to integrate the raw outputs of the accelerometer of an IMU to find its position in the flat-Earth frame. Using the DCM, I changed the frame of the acceleration first, removed the gravity component, and then integrated twice to find the position. I was therefore doing the frame change before the first integration, and it worked, while for the rocket modelisation I have to do it after.

Could you please explain what I am missing ? I suppose I am getting confused with the frames that I am using, but I cannot figure out where. What would be the correct solution for both cases ?

Thank you very much for your time, I hope I explained my problem clearly enough.

Comment: Indices  B or E are  in which system  the components of your vectors are given, but not in which coordinate system the time derivative is taken in B system or in E system. This is probably your problem?

Comment: That could be it, but then it would mean that I should change the coordinate system before integrating. But I found that I obtained the correct answer (using pre-made Simulink blocks) when I change the coordinate system after the first integration..

Comment: That does make sense to me, I feel it should be the correct way to do it, however it turns out that I obtain the same results as the 6DOF Simulink block when I use equation 1, which is why I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&\text{the EOM in Inertial system }\\
&\underbrace{\frac{d}{dt}\,v_E}_{a_E}=\frac{1}{m}\,F_E=\frac{1}{m}\, R\,F_B\tag 1\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\text{the EOM in Body-system}\\
&\underbrace{\frac{d}{d\tau}\,v_B}_{a_B}=\frac{1}{m}\,F_B-\omega_B\times v_B\tag 2\\
\end{align*}
**velocity and position relative to inertial system**

from Eq (1)
\begin{align*}
  &v_E=\int a_E\,dt\\
  &x_E=\int v_E\,dt\\
\end{align*}
or from Eq. (2)
\begin{align*}
  &v_B=\int a_B\,dt\\
  &x_B=\int v_B\,dt\\
  &\text{and the kinematic equation}\\
  &\underbrace{\frac{d}{dt}\,x}_{(v_E)_B}=\underbrace{\frac{d}{d\tau}\,x}_{v_B}+
  \omega_B\times\,x_B\quad\Rightarrow\\\\
  &v_E=R\,(v_E)_B\\
  &x_E=\int v_E\,dt
\end{align*}

- R transformation matrix between Body and Inertial system
- F sum off all external forces (also weight forces)
- E Inertial system components
- B Body system components

---

external weight force in body system
$$(F_g)_B:=m\,\vec g_B=m\,R^T\,\vec{g}_E$$

Comment: The kinematic equation that I was using was : $$\left(\frac{d}{dt}v_E\right)_B=\frac{d}{dt}v_B + \omega_B\times v_B$$ which correspond to Eq 2. Then I obtain $v_B$ by integrating $a_B$, and then $v_E$ with $v_E = R v_B$. But in this case I am using the first equation from my initial message.

Comment: I believe I understood something. Actually Simulink is computing $\left(\frac{d}{dt}v_B\right)_B$, which means that you first need to integrate to find $v_B$. Alright, it makes sense, then you can use the DCM to find $v_E$. But why couldn't we first integrate to find $x_B$, and then use the DCM to find $x_E$ ? It would be the third possibility : $$\textbf{a}_B \xrightarrow{\int} \textbf{v}_B \xrightarrow{\int} \textbf{x}_B \xrightarrow{DCM}\textbf{x}_E$$ I tried this using MatLab, and the results are different. Why ? I am asking because I think it would help me to understand what I'm missing.

Comment: I think that your  $~x_E~$ is not the integration over the velocity relative to inertial frame $\frac{d}{dt}x_E=v_E(t)$.  thus you must use the kinematic equation to obtain $x_E$

Comment: That would make sense. I'll try to see if it works this way. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!